# Remove domain information from login id in C#

Tags: c#, string, indexof

I would like to remove the domain/computer information from a login id in C#.  So, I would like to make either "Domain\me" or "Domain\me" just "me".  I could always check for the existence of either, and use that as the index to start the substring...but I am looking for something more elegant and compact.

Worse case scenario:

```
int startIndex = 0;
int indexOfSlashesSingle = ResourceLoginName.IndexOf("\");
int indexOfSlashesDouble = ResourceLoginName.IndexOf("\\");
if (indexOfSlashesSingle != -1)
    startIndex = indexOfSlashesSingle;
else
    startIndex = indexOfSlashesDouble;
string shortName = ResourceLoginName.Substring(startIndex, ResourceLoginName.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.....

use a razor blade ----

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string domainUser = Regex.Replace("domain\\user",".*\\\\(.*)", "$1",RegexOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine(domainUser);  

    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent point; using RegEx is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: And what if the name is username@domain.com format? Any 5-razer blade solution there? Thanks.

Comment: Had to also do this recently (removing domain portion from `NTAccount`) and came up with either `Regex.Match(value, "([^\\\\]+)$", RegexOptions.None).Groups[0].Captures[0].Value` for extracting the account name portion directly, or `Regex.Replace(value, "^.*\\\\", string.Empty, RegexOptions.None);` for removing everything up to the desired account name. Same difference :)

Comment: @"^(?:[^\\]+\\)?([^\\]+)$" allows for matching usernames with and without domain.

Answer (score 27):

You could abuse the Path class, thusly:

```
string shortName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ResourceLoginName);
```

Comment: Probably best to use System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ResourceLoginName) in case ResourceLoginName has a dot within it (e.g., roger.smith), which is perfectly permissible in terms of Active Directory and presumably other directory systems.

Answer (score 6):

How's about:

```
string shortName = ResourceLoginName.Split('\\')[1]
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work for both but with named groups.

```
^(?<domain>.*)\\(?<username>.*)|(?<username>[^\@]*)@(?<domain>.*)?$
```

Answer (score 3):

I always do it this way:

```
    string[] domainuser;
    string Auth_User = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].ToString().ToLower(); 
    domainuser = Auth_User.Split('\\');
```

Now you can look at domainuser.Length to see how many parts are there and domainuser[0] for the domain and domainuser[1] for the username.

Answer (score 3):

This works for both valid domain logins:

```
var regex = @"^(.*\\)?([^\@]*)(@.*)?$";
var user = Regex.Replace("domain\\user", regex, "$2", RegexOptions.None);
user = Regex.Replace("user@domain.com", regex, "$2", RegexOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        string theString = "domain\\me";
        theString = theString.Split(new char[] { '\\' })[theString.Split(new char[] { '\\' }).Length - 1];
```

Comment: Yep, that's how I do it too with the addition of BoltBait's conversion to lower, because it's always helpful to have the usernames in a "controlled" casing (if using them as indexer keys for instance.

Comment: Good point, Kevin.  I also figured that speed was definitely not an issue in this case, hence the multiple calls to split, etc.  Makes for ugly code, but...

Answer (score 2):

Piggy backing on Derek Smalls Answer...

```
Regex.Replace(User.Identity.Name,@"^(?<domain>.*)\\(?<username>.*)|(?<username>[^\@]*)@(?<domain>.*)?$", "${username}", RegexOptions.None)
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement of @Drew's answer

```
User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last()
```

This way you can also match usernames with and without domain