# Built-in helper to parse User.Identity.Name into Domain\Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, active-directory

Is there any built-in utility or helper to parse `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, e.g. `domain\user` to get separately domain name if exists and user?

Or is there any other class to do so?

I understand that it's very easy to call `String.Split("\")` but just interesting

Comment: It's the simple questions we always forget to ask ourselves. Will look forward to any useful answers to this question.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is better (*easier to use, no opportunity of `NullReferenceExcpetion` and conforms MS coding guidelines about treating empty and null string equally*):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetDomain(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        string s = identity.Name;
        int stop = s.IndexOf("\\");
        return (stop > -1) ?  s.Substring(0, stop) : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string GetLogin(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        string s = identity.Name;
        int stop = s.IndexOf("\\");
        return (stop > -1) ? s.Substring(stop + 1, s.Length - stop - 1) : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IIdentity id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
id.GetLogin();
id.GetDomain();
```

This requires C# 3.0 compiler (or newer) and doesn't require 3.0 .Net for working after compilation.

Comment: Your return statement in `GetLogin` can be simplified to `return s.Substring(stop + 1);`

Comment: What if the username has multiple back-slashes? What if the user wants to use the UPN format of user@domain.com? I ended up using the Win32 function CredUIParseUserName. See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduiparseusername

Answer (score 13):

`System.Environment.UserDomainName` gives you the domain name only

Similarly, `System.Environment.UserName` gives you the user name only

Comment: > System.Environment.UserDomainName` gives you the domain name only
> > Similarly, `System.Environment.UserName` gives you the user name only This will not work on ASP.NET

Comment: I think it works if you use authentication=Windows and impersonation=true. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841816/system-web-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-vs-system-environment-username

Answer (score 7):

```
var components = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

var userName = components.Last() 

var domainName = components.Reverse().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 5):

You guys might also consider parsing a string input like "user@company.com", or "user@domain".

This is what I'm currently doing:
If string contains '\' then split string at '\' and extract username and domain
Else If string contains '@' then split string at '@' and extract username and domain
Else treat string as username without a domain

I'm still hunting for a better solution in the case where the input string isn't in an easily predicted format, i.e. "domain\user@domain". I'm thinking RegEx...

Update: I stand corrected. My answer is a bit of out context, it refers to the general case of parsing username and domains out of user input, like in user login/logon prompt. Hope it still helps someone.

Comment: Need an elegant solution for this. I agree. One answer to the domain\user part is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/185716/481656

Answer (score 4):

I think No too, because I asked myself the same question the other day :D

You can try:

```
public static string GetDomain(string s)
{
    int stop = s.IndexOf("\\");
    return (stop > -1) ? s.Substring(0, stop + 1) : null;
}

public static string GetLogin(string s)
{
    int stop = s.IndexOf("\\");
    return (stop > -1) ? s.Substring(stop + 1, s.Length - stop - 1) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, because System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity doesn't contain such members.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a .NET built-in, one can always P/Invoke to [CredUIParseUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduiparseusername)'s a example of how to use it in .NET.

PS: It doesn't seem to handle the "dot", as in ".\username".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem made to be solved by regular expressions:

```
public static class UserExtensions
{
    public static string GetDomain(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        Regex.Match(identity.Name, ".*\\\\").ToString()
    }

    public static string GetLogin(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(identity.Name, ".*\\\\", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't using regex an overkill here when simple string manipulating may be used instead?

Comment: Sounds like: I have a problem. Let's use regex. Now I have two problems :)

Comment: A regex solves the problem in one simple line. They're not the right tool for every job but I think in this case the regex solution is more elegant.