# How to parse employee's domain and Id with "\" in between?

Tags: c#, .net

I am seeking to parse out the Employee's Id from strings that contain my company's domain.  For example:

```
domain\empId  --> all I want is "empId"
test\x123  --> all I want is "x123"
qa\e24  --> all I want is "e24"
```

Basically, given a string, I would like everything after the "\".

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET built-in helper to parse Domain\Username in User.Identity.Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349520/net-built-in-helper-to-parse-domain-username-in-user-identity-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string s = @"domain\empId";
string value = s.Split('\\')[1];
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output:

```
empId
```

Comment: This is not as efficient as mine... although we are talking milliseconds and microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = inputString.Split(@"\")[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf('\\')+1);
```

This is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringVar.Split("\\")[1]` and check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx for details.

Comment: You fell into the trap I almost did ... "\" is bad, it'll escape the quote and not compile.  You want "\\".

Comment: Yep - typo city.  I like Mahesh's `@"\"` best for readability, actually.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```