# Display The Window User Name On My Web Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

hope if someone can help me.
i have a simple webpage nad i want to display a windows user name on my webpage.
i just need the user name from the windows on my webpage.

i had use some codes do do that but no result like

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

but it is giving me empty string

also i have tried

system.envoirement.username

its work when i run it from vistual studio but this code not give me the right answer when ii run it from IIS. 
i am going to use this webpage as my Intranet on local network.

any reply will be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You're looking for NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do to get the user name is with the following code:

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

If you are using Visual Studio 2012, then from your project setting you have to turn SSL to true.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you are looking for User.Identity.Name which inherits from System.Web.HttpContext.

```
myLabel.Text = User.Identity.Name
```

Be sure IIS is set up for some type of windows authentication, (as SLaks indicated), rather than anonymous authentication.

Also, see this SO link:  [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name Vs System.Environment.UserName in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841816/system-web-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-vs-system-environment-username)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i have tried this line of code before but it is giving me empty string. i know that might be my question is bit silly. but i dont know where i am going wrong. as i have done this in past , but nothing is working this time... :(

Comment: I believe VS pulls the user name of the currently logged in user on your development machine, so how are you authenticating on your actual site?  Can you tell us what IIS authentication settings you are using, as well as show us your code to assign the identity to your HTML control?

Comment: connection.Open() 
Dim MyReader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()
If MyReader.Read() Then 
Dim User_id As String = MyReader.GetValue(0).ToString
Session("User_ID") = user_id
response.redirect("nest_pasge.aspx")
else
response.redirect("Error_page.aspx")
end if
connection.close()

Comment: IIS SETTING IS SET TO APPLICATION POOL AS I AM GIVING TEH USER NAME AND PASSWORD IN THE CONNECTION STRING TO GET ACCESS INTO THE DATABASE.

Comment: Have you verified whether you are authenticating?  Something like, If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name
Else
    Label1.Text = "Anonymous user"
End If

Comment: yes i did try that, and that is the point where i am loosing everything because when i am doing if User.Identity.IsAuthenticated its gives me false althought its supose to be true....:D because i did check the user before that...!

Comment: I would direct your efforts toward your web server.  Authentication = false indicates that you need to check that your authentication type is set up correctly.  Are you being prompted for authentication when you request your page from your IIS site?