# cshtml file - Locate current windows user, then query database

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am working on a localhost site that queries, and updates a database. I have not worked with ASP.NET very much.

I am wondering if it would be possible to find out the current windows user, then select all records in the database that match the located username.

I know how to do this with vbscript, but I need to make it work in a cshtml file.

1. How do I locate the user?
2. What would my select sentence look like?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here is the code that I use to display data from a specific user:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("Database") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = 'asmith'";
var searchTerm = "";

var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);
var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Team", rowsPerPage:20);

}
```

When I change `WHERE UserID = 'asmith'` to `WHERE UserID = @Environment.UserName`, I receive the error:

`There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 48,Token in error = . ]` and the below is highlighted in red.

```
Line 15:     var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);
```

Edit #2:

This Successfully queries the database and returns the correct data, but isn't clean and is causing an issue with another query on the page.

```
var CurrUser = Environment.UserName;
var db = Database.Open("Database") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = @0";
var searchTerm = @CurrUser;
```

Comment: Going through the [Create an Intranet Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) may help. What you are looking for is called Windows Authentication.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev This will be useful and might be the way to go, though I would like to figure out how to send the username in a query without the Authentication as well. The user should already be Authenticated. I just want the UserID for logging and viewing purposes. I am able to use `@Environment.UserName` to display the current user, but for some reason I can't successfully add it to a SELECT sentence. I would like to do something like `var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Database WHERE UserID = @Environment.UserName"; `

Comment: Please include you code for your `SELECT` and whatever error you are having.

Comment: I have included my code and error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clean up and resolve an old post, I would change the select to something more like this:

```
var currentUser = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = @0";
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, currentUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the single quotes:

```
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = 'asmith'";
```

should be:

```
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = '@" + Environment.UserName + "'";
```

`Environment.UserName` is a `string`.  You're querying where `UserID`.  Are you sure `UserID` shouldn't be an `int` or some `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = '@" + Environment.UserName + "'";` removed the error, but does not return any data. `UserID` is not an `int`. As far as being a `uniqueidentifier`, there could be multiple occurrences.

Comment: What happens when you query SQL directly with `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = 'SOMEUSERTHATEXISTS'`?  You should step through the code and make sure that `Environment.UserName` is giving you the username you expect.  How are the names getting into your database to begin with?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = 'SOMEUSERTHATEXISTS'` correctly returns all records that match the query. It is when I try to use a variable that it is not working. `@Environment.UserName` placed in the body of the page displays the current username, so that is why I am stumped. Right now I am manually entering the `UserID`, but my goal will be to automatically write the username to the database when a user inputs information, then read all records `WHERE` the Username matches the `UserID` from the database.

Comment: Did you set a break point and make sure that the username is actually getting passed to the query?  `Environment.UserName` may be returning the app pool your site is running under.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841816/system-web-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-vs-system-environment-username

Comment: I am slightly confused. If I do this: `var CurrUser = Environment.UserName;` I am able to successfully write `@CurrUser` to the database, So I would expect that I could use `@CurrUser` in my query. Like this: `SELECT * FROM Board WHERE UserID = '@" + CurrUser + "'";`, but that doesn't work. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It does answer my question but now I'm in the same position as you.  I'll put a bounty on this question if not answered by the time it's eligible for a bounty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24003/discussion-between-jack-and-pete)

Comment: I added a little bit more code up top where I was able to make it work but not in a clean way, because it messed up another query on the page.