# How do I access the credentials in web service that the user has set while calling the webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, asmx, soap-client

I have a webservice e.g.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SI_C : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public SI_C()
{

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[Webmethod]

public bool CreateRecord(classname objname) //some class I am setting the data to
{
   //Creates a record.
}
}
```

Now while consuming at client side I created

```
 SI_C_In_SoapClient client = new SI_C_In_SoapClient("SI_C");
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username Sent";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Passport Sent";
```

Now I want to access this sent password and username in my webservice. How would I do that?

Update:

1. Set the password and username at client side using network credentials call
2. Receive that in webservice
3. Send to database and check if ok? That's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly dependent upon how you configured your web server app.  If using IIS then the answer to this question is entirely driven by how you set up security.

Look into `HttpContext.Current.User` or `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` here is the link:

Respectively:

[How does HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name know which usernames exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117617/how-does-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-know-which-usernames-exist)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_CredentialCache_DefaultNetworkCredentials

Comment: I just want to access the credentials in the web service that are being set in client app before calling.

Comment: are you using integrated security?  you need to detail how your security is configured on the web server.  If the security is set to integrated then `HttpContext.Current.User` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I will just check the username and password against the database.

Comment: 1. Set the password and username at client side using network credentials call
2. Receive that in webservice
3. Send to database and check if ok? That's it.

Comment: huh???  a web service isn't going to work with sql server authentication...

Comment: I just want to get those set credentials in webservice. that;s it

Comment: I am not understanding what you are telling me. doesn't make sense.

Comment: @T McKeown: See, I have a client app from where I am calling web service (that's mine too). Now at client side I am setting credentials using NetworkCredentials class. So, after calling the webservice, at that end I want to get those credentials. That's it.