# Cant get HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to return values

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext, windows-identity

This project authenticates with System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity

I had a look at this:
[Can't get HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to work in my WebMatrix project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384891/cant-get-httpcontext-current-user-identity-to-work-in-my-webmatrix-project)

```
        IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;//returns no data
        WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
```

I have disabled anonymous in my Web.config

http://forums.asp.net/t/1901573.aspx?System+web+HttpContext+Current+User+Identity+Name+returns+Empty+string

```
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

The wierd part is I have another project that uses the same code and has has the same .config but works,

Comment: Did you install the Windows authentication role service on IIS? http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/providers

Comment: Have you run your application on same domain or different domains?

Comment: Yes It is Enabled, Regardless - same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you wrote this in your web config ??

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

and please just take a look this

[System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name Vs System.Environment.UserName in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841816/system-web-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-vs-system-environment-username)

Comment: Yes I have, I cant use **System.Environment.UserName** since this is an intranet application