# ASP.NET web application -- how to get Windows user?

Tags: asp.net, iis

My legacy ASP.NET Framework 4.5 (Windows auth) web site running in IIS uses the following code to get the Windows user id (to assess permissions):

```
String Name = System.Environment.UserName;
```

Looking at a log of this string, the Windows user ID isn't obtained correctly; rather, the name corresponding to the application pool credentials is obtained.

Is this due to using impersonation in `web.config`:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="app_user" password="xxxx" />
```

Or can I change a setting in IIS to correct this?

The web site used to work correctly. Something was changed in IIS and now it doesn't...

In web.config, windows authentication is specified:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />. . .
```

UPDATE: by enabling Anonymous Authentication (impersonation) in IIS for the web application itself, I was able to overcome this issue.

Comment: You should never again set `userName` and `password` in `identity` tag. To configure an identity for the whole web application you should use application pool identity. To query the log on user information in your legacy ASP.NET web apps, use `Page.User` or `Controller.User` please. Don't know how you get started with this web app, but there are tons of samples over the internet telling the right way to go.

Comment: You might read my blog post for more details, https://blog.lextudio.com/miseries-around-asp-net-windows-authentication-setup-14e2e8522ad2

Answer (score 0):

> uses the following code to get the Windows user id (to assess permissions):

> String Name = System.Environment.UserName;

If you already implemented the Windows auth within your ASP.NET app (actually, the following code is enough):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Retrieve the necessary info via the [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user) / System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name property value (wherever you are - ASPX Page Code Behind, ASP.NET MVC Controller, any ASP.NET app module):

Check out some related threads to understand the differences:
[System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name Vs System.Environment.UserName in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841816)

ASPX Page Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Page.User
    ...
}
```

ASP.NET MVC Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
        //User
    }
}
```

any ASP.NET app module:

```
public class X {
    public void Y() {
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry: the code where I am retrieving user name is in ASPX page code behind.

Comment: Check our my first code snippet.

Comment: thank you; that code is already in web.config. I will update my question.

Comment: Does my code work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the code. The issue turned out to be with IIS Anonymous Auth being disabled. I have stuck with the original code.

Comment: BTW, `HttpContext.Current` can be `null` if you don't know. And "actually, the following code is enough" is in fact not enough. That snippet in `web.config` works even if anonymous/Basic/Digest authentication is used on IIS so don't expect it to enforce Windows authentication.