# Will the domain name ever be absent from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, httpcontext

I'm working on a simple one page ASP.Net site used inside the company by a limited number of users.

In it, I use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` to get the logged user's name in the format **Domain\ActiveDirectoryUserName** and stripping out the domain name as suggested by the answer in this post: [Built-in helper to parse User.Identity.Name into Domain\Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349520/net-built-in-helper-to-parse-domain-username-in-user-identity-name) and display it in a label like ***Hello xyz***

Will there ever be a scenario, where the Domain name will *not be present* in `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`?

---

UPDATE: This site uses Windows Authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if the user is anonymous, you'll get an empty string for the user's identity.

Secondly, there is only a domain present when you're using an authentication source which supports domains. If you're using Windows Integrated Authentication under IIS, the domain will always be present in every non-anonymous user identity. If you're using forms authentication or another authentication source, the provider has full control over the format of the user's identity.

---

As you've indicated you're using Windows Integrated Authentication, you'll always have  a domain, provided the user is authenticated. If you allow anonymous access, you should check that `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` first before trying to parse their name.