# Remove string with starts with "/" and ends with "\" in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a login username as a string and I would like to remove a substring from that username. e.g. `username= "ABC/Domain-name\Pinto"` So in this case, I want only `ABC/Pinto` or only `"Pinto"` as a output. Kindly assist me on this.

This is my current code.

```
var removeDomainName= userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: If the format of input string is always the same you can use `Split('\\')` that returns an array and take the element at `[1]`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed to have at most one `'/'` and one `'\\'`? If there can be more of them, what is the desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Built-in helper to parse User.Identity.Name into Domain\Username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349520/built-in-helper-to-parse-user-identity-name-into-domain-username).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to try to use regular expression. Once you familiar with it, string manipulation will be a much easier task for you.

```
string input = @"ABC/Domain-name\Pinto";
string regex = @"(\/){1}(\w.*)(\\){1}";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "/");
```

Try it here: http://regexr.com/3e8l0

Simplified REGEX according to @grek40 comment

```
string input = @"ABC/Domain-name\Pinto";
string regex = @"(\/.*\\)";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "/");
```

Comment: Why do you have the `\w` in it and why so many braces and count qualifiers? Regex is the right approach, but I think your expression can be simplified.

Comment: Having both, the verbose and the minimal approach looks fine. You already have my +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
string userName = @"ABC/Domain-name\Pinto";
string[] arrCompany = userName.Split('/');
Console.WriteLine(arrCompany[0] +"/"+ arrCompany[1].Split('\\')[1]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one but the output given by this code is 
"Domain-name\Pinto" 

But I want the output "ABC/Pinto". What should I do to get this output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edit my answer, all I have change is this line Console.WriteLine(arrCompany[0] +"/"+ arrCompany[1].Split('\\')[1]);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
string userName = @"ABC/Domain-name\Pinto";
int pos = userName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
Console.WriteLine(userName.Substring(pos, userName.Length - pos));
```

Another way to do is to replace all the `\` with `/` so that it is easier to split. Then, combine them according to your need.

```
string userName = @"ABC/Domain-name\Pinto";
string edit = userName.Replace('\\', '/');
string[] split = edit.Split(new Char[] {'/'}); 
string final = split[0] + "/" + split[2];
Console.WriteLine(final);
```

If you want to keep the backslash, you can replace

```
string[] split = edit.Split(new Char[] {'/'});
```

with

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(edit, @"(?<=[/])");
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the second one but the output given by this code is "ABCPinto". Bit closer. But I want the output "ABC/Pinto". 

What should I do to get this output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add a backslash at string final = split[0] + split[2];. please check the edited code. you can check it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTqbmS. also, if you read the last part, you can also get your desired output.

Comment: Hi, And what if in userName having plane value like "Admin" then the string final = split[0] + "/" + split[2]; line gives error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: @Vinci wrap it up with if-else statement. Check this out https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8rTZi

Answer (score 0):

You can split the three parts:

```
var splitted = userName.Split(new char[] {'\\', '/'});
```

Where `split[0]` would be your prefix (`ABC`), `split[1]` will be your domain (`Domain-name`) and `split[2]` will be your username (`Pinto`)

I've made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zvbwZi

Alternatively, you can substring it:

To get the prefix and the username (e.g. `ABC\Pinto`):

```
var prefix = userName.Substring(0, userName.IndexOf('/'));
var user = userName.Substring(userName.LastIndexOf('\\'));
var prefixAndUser = prefix + user;
```

Then to get just the username (e.g. `Pinto`):

```
var userNameWithoutPrefixOrDomain = user.Substring(1);
```

Or if you want the forward slash (`ABC/Pinto`):

```
var prefix = userName.Substring(0, userName.IndexOf('/')+1);
var user = userName.Substring(userName.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
```

In this case, `user` will already be your username

I've made a fiddle too: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7YL0m5

Answer (score 0):

```
private string ParseString(string inString)
{
  string prefix = "";
  string suffix = "";
  string[] splitStringArray;

  splitStringArray = inString.Split('/');
  prefix = splitStringArray[0];
  if (prefix != "ABC")
  {
    prefix = "";
  }
  splitStringArray = inString.Split('\\');
  suffix = splitStringArray[1];
  if (prefix != "")
  {
    //MessageBox.Show("Result: " + prefix + "/" + suffix);
    return prefix + "/" + suffix;
  }
  else
  {
    return suffix;
  }
}
```

Just an Example

Regular Expressions are the best rout for parsing strings