# Dsiplay Login Name without the Domain name (No Java Script)

Tags: asp.net

This is my default.aspx file

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Default2" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   </head>
    <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
    Welcome to sample website:)
   </div>
     <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>

        <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Welcome,{0}" />

    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to display the doaminname\username but I need to display only the username . i am confused how do I go ahead with this.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try <LoggedInTemplate><asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server" FormatString="Welcome,{0}"></asp:LoginName></LoggedInTemplate> [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx#Y0)

Comment: No didn't work!!

Comment: did you read the source I linked as well?

Comment: Yes i did have a look at it!

Comment: Are you getting any error at all or is it just empty?

Comment: I am getting the output with domain name which do not want to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your page_load

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if (windowsIdentity == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowsIdentity is null");
string nameWithoutDomain = windowsIdentity.Name.Split('\\').Last();

LoginName1.Text = String.Format("Welcome,{0}", nameWithoutDomain)
```

And if you want a helper class you can refer to this [Built-in helper to parse User.Identity.Name into Domain\Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349520/built-in-helper-to-parse-user-identity-name-into-domain-username)

Comment: it says LoginName1 does not exist in the current context!